# How to send email from my G-Suite account using Django and OAuth 2?

Tags: django, email, google-workspace

How to send email from my G-Suite account using Django and OAuth 2 ? I am using Django to send email but its asking me to make my account enable for less secure app. I don't want to do that, I want to use OAuth 2 in my app and send email from my G Suite account.